# What type of drywall tape should I use for a drywall to plaster patch?

Tags: drywall, plaster

What would be the best drywall tape for drywall to plaster patch? 
The patch is on a non-insulated garage ceiling, so there will be temperature swings from 0 to 100 probably through the year.

I had to patch because of some water damage, the old material is plaster over rocklathe (3/4" total), and new is just a dual layer of 3/8" drywall.

I have setting type compound, but I'm not sure of which tape would hold up better for these circumstances.

[image]

Comment: Is there living space on the other side of that?

Comment: Nope, just an attic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like the mesh tape for this sort of thing - because you can get material through it, and it seems less prone to peel.

The self-adhesive aspect is not all that significant - it's merely holding it (barely) in place until it's embedded in compound. The compound is what actually sticks things together.

Comment: +1.  I recently had a bunch of this kind of work and used a special (blue) mesh tape that, i believe, was marketed for this specific purpose (or thereabouts).  i bought it at Home Depot

Comment: I'll see if I can find some of that wide tape, might have to go to a drywall store to get it though.  I have time though, it's not going to be above 50 degrees in the garage until spring :)

Comment: +1 Look for the thick blue tape - usually marketed as plaster tape (not drywall). Fibers are thicker, glue is super sticky, even on dusty surfaces, and it is a tad wider.

Comment: https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/drywall/drywall-tape/300-veneer-plaster-tape/p-1444450692654-c-13061.htm?tid=-2790206722416456607

Answer (score 5):

## Fiberglass Mesh Tape

Fiberglass mesh tapes are usually self adhesive and easy to use, so tend to be the tape of choice for many DIYers.

[image]

Mesh tapes tend to be a bit thicker, and require more compound to cover.

Mesh tapes are self adhesive, so once they're stuck they don't tend to bubble or peal later.

## Paper Tape

Paper tapes can be a bit more difficult to work with, which can lead to highly visible seams when used by inexperienced users.

[image]

Paper tapes are a bit thinner, so typically requiring less compound to cover. Though it must be set in compound, so *may* require more coats.

If paper tape is not set properly in compound, it can bubble and/or wrinkle as the compound dries.

Comment: I've always found paper to be the way to go.  I get a better finish with it.

Answer (score -1):

Tape will not fix this mess. You need to first pull the sheetrock down and shim it so that it's flush and fits the hole. You should try to get 1/4" or lower gap. Then tape it and spackle.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about which type of tape to use. FWIW it looks relatively flush in the picture.

Comment: Ceiling is RockLathe with Plaster coat, so it's near impossible to get a perfectly clean cut on.  Patch panel does have extra framing behind it so it's not being supported by the existing plasterwork though.